# Crystal Reports won't let me sort by a formula

Tags: crystal-reports

I have a report grouped by provider and then patientID. I have a formula which gives the last time since an interaction between the clinic and a patient occurred. I want simply to sort the results by that measure. I have created a flag that marks 1 if the time measured is 6 months or greater and 0 if not on the detail level but this does not allow me to sort either.

Code:

```
DateDiff("m",maximum({Ticket.TicketDate},{Ticket.PatientID}),CurrentDateTime)
```

@flag

```
if {@TimeSinceLastInteraction} >= 6 then 1
else 0
```

All help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is particularly frustrating is that I have already sorted on a formula that works in exactly the same way as the @flag. So I'm guessing that perhaps there is an interaction in the sort that I don't understand or a limit to what can be sorted on..?

Comment: You cannot sort by any formula that uses a summary function. If you want to sort by that value you'll need to calculate it server-side via a subquery/SQL expression.

Answer (score 0):

A possible workaround would be to export to XLS (data only) and do sort with excel.